# Mac OS X launchd: forbid starting a process in Power Nap (dark wake)?

Tags: macos, bash, sleep, launchd

What would be the best way to forbid Mac OS 10.10+ `Launchd` to start a Bash script when a MacBook is in Power Nap (dark wake)?

Is there an elegant way to limit it only to "real wake", like:

`<key>RunOnlyWhenInRealWake</key><true/>` ?

I haven’t found anything specific in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)

I have a bash script which sometimes executes in Power Nap and has no time to finish before Mac OS goes back to sleep.

I’ve tried prepending a `sleep 15` timer to the script… would like to avoid having to lengthen that to, say, 5 minutes.

Thanks!

Comment: Off topic: belongs to Ask Different

Comment: @Matteo — Gruezi, danke, have moved the question to Ask Different

Comment: @AnatolyIVANOV Did you ever find anything regarding this? I'm using sleepwatcher to detect sleep/wake and run custom scripts based on that, but I haven't tested if power nap triggers these, but I'm assuming so. I'm also assuming that power nap wouldn't necessarily wait for my custom scripts to finish either.

Comment: @Dids — I apologize for missing your comment! Somehow didn’t get the notification.

No, still haven't found anything about it.

I ended up running the script through caffeinate.

`<string>com.anatolyivanov.BashScript</string>`
`<key>ProgramArguments</key>`
`<array>`
`<string>/usr/bin/caffeinate</string>`
`<string>-i</string>`
`<string>/Users/anatolyivanov.com/Applications/BashScript.sh</string>`
`</array>`

I'd guesstimate 80% of my Bash script during Power Nap do pass through and finish, but 20% are cutoff (process hangs, broken pipes…)